# Rereading the grid does not change the pager

Tags: kendo-ui

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The problem is like the picture above.

The query retrieved a new record, but the paging number did not change.

It was 1, 2 because it fetches 10 records per page, but now only 1 should be displayed because it is only 1.

The page does not disappear until you select a blank page.

What is the cause?
This little problem bothers me very much.

Comment: Share some code so we can better help you. What you can do is trying to refresh the grid after removing the line like this: $('#GridName').data('kendoGrid').refresh(); Anyway, please just post a minimal reproducible code in your question.